# Unable to write HTML in pdf with python due to unescaped html

Tags: python, html, pdf, html-parsing

I'm trying to write in a pdf and it doesn't works due to the following issue
"text = h2p.unescape(text) # To deal with HTML entities
AttributeError: 'HTML2FPDF' object has no attribute 'unescape'"

I tried to unescape my html with html.unescape without success.

Here my code as I'm clueless.

```
from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin

class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass
html= """
  <h1>Big title</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Section title</h2>
    <p><b>Hello</b> world. <u>I am</u> <i>tired</i>.</p>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2">PyFPDF/fpdf2 GitHub repo</a></p>
    <p align="right">right aligned text</p>
    <p>i am a paragraph <br />in two parts.</p>
    <font color="#00ff00"><p>hello in green</p></font>
    <font size="7"><p>hello small</p></font>
    <font face="helvetica"><p>hello helvetica</p></font>
    <font face="times"><p>hello times</p></font>
  </section>
"""
pdf = PDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.write_html(test)
pdf.output("html.pdf")
```

Comment: What happens when you try the example here, https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write_html/index.html?

Comment: Also in that link are supported tags, and <section> is not supported. Even <div> is not supported. The only layout control you have is through <table>.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyFPDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    def write_html(self, text, image_map=None):
        h2p = HTML2FPDF(self, image_map)
        h2p.feed(text)

html= """
  <h1>Big title</h1>
  <section>
    <h2>Section title</h2>
    <p><b>Hello</b> world. <u>I am</u> <i>tired</i>.</p>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2">PyFPDF/fpdf2 GitHub repo</a></p>
    <p align="right">right aligned text</p>
    <p>i am a paragraph <br />in two parts.</p>
    <font color="#00ff00"><p>hello in green</p></font>
    <font size="7"><p>hello small</p></font>
    <font face="helvetica"><p>hello helvetica</p></font>
    <font face="times"><p>hello times</p></font>
  </section>
 """

pdf = MyFPDF()

#First page
pdf.add_page()
pdf.write_html(html)
pdf.output('html.pdf', 'F')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).